# TCL Regexp for extracting months from a string

Tags: regex, tcl

I am expecting strings which has month prefixs like JAN, FEB , MAR...

My regex till now ...(J[AU][NL]|FEB|MA[RY]|APR|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)...

Can you guys go any shorter or is there any less ugly alternative??

Thanks

Comment: The regular expression will match `JAL`.

Comment: MY bad!!. please go shorter without including Garbage values like JAL

Comment: I am not expecting JAL in my strings so, you can take as an exception...

Comment: I'd just list them all out literally (`(JAN|FEB|…|NOV|DEC)`) since the RE compiler will sort out the mess easily and the clarity of description of intent is better than trying to make the RE text as short as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The less ugly, and far more efficient, alternative is to use the `in` operator from `expr`.

```
expr {$month in {JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC}}
```

or

```
if {$month in {JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC}} {
    ...
}
```

This is an order of magnitude faster, clearer to look at, and you don't get any false positives.

---

As Donal Fellows notes, if one must use a regexp, it's better to use an explicit one (`(JAN|FEB|…|NOV|DEC)`) since it's more clear. Now, I've never ventured into the regex engine source code to see how it works (nor would I unless one of my kids was lost in there), but I'm pretty sure that the recognition chains that the engine builds for this expression are at least as efficient as whatever clever abbreviation you or I could come up with.

Another thing: is there any chance you might want to internationalize the application? Abbreviated month names are the same in most countries (in the West, at least), but there are some differences. With Tcl it's very easy to get localized lists of abbreviated month names either by extracting them from `clock` or by keeping your own lists and using the `msgcat` package. If you create your regexp like this:

```
set re ([join [lmap m {0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11} {lindex [::msgcat::mc MONTHS_ABBREV] $m}] |])
```

and later someone wants to change the language of the application, you just re-create it. It's much harder to do this if you want to craft your own regular expressions as in your question above.

Comment: My strings are bigger than you think & these prefix are just a small part of it and one string will contain only one month prefix.

Comment: @AnilBisht: it's not clear what you need, neither from your question nor from your comment here. The only thing that can be said with any certainty is that making the search expression shorter will not improve your program. It will not be more reliable, faster, or easier to maintain. Always prefer the sane solution to the clever one.